# How is it possible that a null pointer still retains a memory adress?

Tags: c++

When you initialize a pointer with nothing(NULL), that element still has a memory address big enough for the initialising type of that pointer(4 bytes for int, 1 for char etc.) but why,since it's tehnically nothing, not even the value zero? I mean, NULL can't be a fixed value like 0 because zero still is considered a value, so it is something more than that?
Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int *a=NULL;
int main()
{
    std::cout <<&a; //it will show the address in hexadecimal system;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you declare an int and set it to 0 is that any different than setting it to 923604? A pointer is the same, it holds a value, whether it is zero or something else.

Comment: `&a` is the address of `a`, nothing problematic here.

Comment: "since it's tehnically nothing, not even the value zero? I mean, NULL can't be a fixed value like 0 because zero still is considered a value". Completely incorrect. Null is a value. Null can be (and often is) `0`. Null is a valid value of  a pointer. A pointer that has the value Null doesn't point to an object.

Answer (score 3):

Your program does not answer the question you were asking. This program shows that, yes the pointer has an address, it needs one to store the value (the address it is pointing to). When you print the value you see that it is indeed `nullptr` (since this is C++ not C).

```
#include <iostream>

int *a= nullptr;
int main()
{
    std::cout << &a << '\n'; // Will show the address OF THE POINTER in hexadecimal system;
    std::cout << a << '\n';  // Will show the address at a is pointing to.
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x601180
0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate, but I don't see any now. You confuse the meaning of operators `*` and `&` in different contexts.

Here, `&p` means "*address of `p`*". And what is `p`? `p` is a ***global*** variable of pointer type. It is perfectly valid to take address of any global variable.

So, to clear things up:

```
#include <iostream>

int *a=NULL;
int main()
{
    std::cout << &a; //perfectly valid, address of p, type int** (pointer-to-pointer-to-int)
    std::cout << a; //still valid, it gives address to where p is pointing, i.e. 0 (NULL)
    std::cout << *a; //wrong, dereferencing an invalid address, there's no memory allocated
    return 0;
}
```

You also seem to have few misconceptions about pointers:

- *"that element still has a memory address big enough for the initialising type of that pointer(4 bytes for int, 1 for char etc.)"*
  Not at all. Pointer is just a pointer. It doesn't care *where* does it point to. In fact, on lower levels it's just plain int. It can point to an array, to an element, to nothing at all or to some wild place where nothing was ever stored.
- "*NULL can't be a fixed value like 0 because zero still is considered a value, so it is something more than that?*"
  Again, pointer is just a pointer. Pointer doesn't know anything at all about value. Value may or may not exist, and the memory where pointer points to may or may not be valid. And in fact, `NULL` is defined to be exactly `0` (or `nullptr` in newer standards): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL